# extraneous background for grant applications

Tags: funding

In many grant applications (the NSF GRFP is the one I have in mind), it seems I need to write about my background and broader impacts of the proposed research.

I am an undergraduate studying math, and I plan to study math in graduate school, but I also have degrees in other areas that I don't plan to pursue further.

I am worried about having such a diverse background with no plans to use it. For example, I don't want to give the appearance that I am unfocused or that I am not serious about studying math. On the other hand, I feel dishonest writing proposals in a way that suggests I do plan to use this background when I do not.

Is this something I should worry about and if so, how can I structure my writing to avoid/allay these concerns?

Comment: Mind sharing what they are? I'm curious to know what subjects would not be, even remotely, related to math.

Comment: I feel not that they are not related, but that I don't want to pursue them further. My original background is in the sciences, particularly chemistry. I realize there are so many ways math could be applied there, but at the moment, it's not something I feel interested in.